# TDF file conversion to VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to convert a big chunk of code from tdf (text design file) to vhdl. 
There is a state machine implemented in this tdf file.

```
Y <= state0 # state1 # state2 # state3   // start at state 0 and stop at state 3
```

How do I write this above statement in VHDL, assuming I have all states defined. 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

[Text Design File (.tdf)](http://quartushelp.altera.com/13.1/mergedProjects/reference/glossary/def_tdf.htm)

> An ASCII text file (with the extension .tdf) written in the Altera Hardware Description Language (AHDL).

AHDL is a VHDL syntax subset superimposed on the majority of the ABEL language syntax (which is more Verilog/C like).

From the ABEL-HDL Reference Manual [ABEL-HDL Reference Manual](http://www.eit.lth.se/fileadmin/eit/courses/edi021/PDF_files/lattice/abel_reference.pdf), Operators, Expressions and Equations page 24, and Table 1-3 Logical Operators Page 25 we see *#* is an OR operator.

There is an AHDL manual See [Altera AHDL Language Reference](http://www.alterawiki.com/wiki/File:Altera_AHDL_Language_Reference.pdf), see Table 3-1. AHDL Symbols (Part 3 of 3) document page 96 (PDF page 117), where we also find *#* is an OR operator (also represented by the OR reserved word, see Table 3-3. Arithmetic Operators and Comparators Used in Arithmetic Expressions (Part 2 of 2), document page 104 (PDF Page 125).

Also see Table 3.4. Logical Operators Used in Boolean Expressions, document page 107 (PDF Page 128).

Also note from your question "<=" isn't an assignment operator in AHDL or ABEL.  (VHDL doesn't have assignment operators, assignment is a a basic operation, operators can be overloaded, basic operations can't be).

Converting this assignment statement depends of whether or not `Y` and `state0` are the same type or not.

If they are the same type:

```
Y <= state0 or state1 or state2 or state3;
```

And you can trust synthesis tools to optimize if possible.

If they are of different types the declarations become necessary. (Historically ABEL identifiers for signals are of the same anonymous type, the question is whether you have declared the types as different).

AHDL doesn't support user defined types but does allow enumerated state names.

That would imply a state type along the lines of

```
type state is (state0, state1, state2, state3, state4,...);
signal sm:  state;
```

And require either a conditional assignment or a case statement.

```
Y <= '1' when sm = state0 or sm = state1 or sm = state2 or 
              sm = state3 else
     '0';
```

In a place appropriate for sequential statements:

```
case sm is
    when state0 | state1 | state2 | state2 =>
        Y <= '1';
    when others =>
        Y <= '0';
end case;
```

or and if statement in a place appropriate for sequential statements:

```
if sm = state0 or sm = state1 or sm = state2 or sm = state3 then  
    Y <= '1';
else
    Y <= '0';
end if;
```

Also see this [VHDL Reference Manual](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/Synario%20VHDL%20Manual.pdf), Appendix C. VHDL for the ABEL-HDL Designer.